# Calculated Field to show difference of hours as value

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, date-time

Hello I have three fields hours1, hours2 and total hours.

Total hours is calculated fields based on the sum of hours1 and hours2.

I use the formula `=VALUE(TEXT(total hours,"hh")`.

It works if sum of the 2 fields are whole numbers. for example. for (18:00 - 16:00) result is 2. But if there are minutes in time i.e. (18:30 -16:00) result will be 2.12, and I am looking for the 2.5 result.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: what formula you have used for Total hours field please post that.

Comment: hi Ganesh...i use a simple addition <!-- =TotHrs1+TotHrs2 -->

Comment: Are they (hours1 and hours2, or "ToHrs1 and TolHrs2") date and time column? You need to provide detail information about your fields.

Comment: Apologies for not making any sense on the initial question...and I will rephrase it.

I am trying to make a sharepoint list for Overtime.  Basically the overtime form has sections for first 12 hours (00:00 - 12:00) and secondly for (12:00 - 00:00).  The fields here are FromHrs1, ToHrs1, FromHrs2, ToHrs2.

There are two calculated field TotHrs1 and TotHrs2 that calculates the difference of the above fields to get the number of overtime hours with the following formula `=ToHrs1-FromHrs1` and `ToHrs2-FromHrs2`

Comment: And lastly another calculated field called HrsEarned is used to sum TotHrs1 and TotHrs2 using the formula `=TotHrs1+TotHrs2`

The above works properly on the list...but there is a requirement for me to show total of overtime hours of staffs on a monthly basis, and I can only do it when creating a new view as Datasheet View.  Since I am unable to get the field HrsEarned in TOTALS...i thought of creating another calculated field called CumputedHours and put the formula `=VALUE(TEXT(HrsEarned,"hh")`.

Comment: This enables this field/column to be included in the TOTALS and performs the summation.  However, this only works if the values of HrsEarned are equal to whole numbers (value), and if there are value like 1.30 (1 hour and 30 minutes), the totals are not calculated properly.  I have tried to change the formula to `=VALUE(TEXT(HrsEarned,"hh.mm")` and values became 0.00...change it to `=VALUE(TEXT(HrsEarned,"hh:mm")` and values became 1.12.

Comment: My question is how can i make the system calculates totals for field ComputedHours properly that if there are 3 overtime lists i.e. 1:00, 2:30, 1:00...ComputedHours total should be 4.30 or 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:

```
=24*(time1-time2)
```

Return Number type with 1 or 2 decimal. Don't select Automatic decimal.